# Connecting java to a mysql domain server

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I've created a java application for our POS project and tried using heliohost.org as my domain server to sync all the data from different branches and uploaded my MySQL database in it. I've successfully connected it, and my application can access the database without any problem.  However, when using the domain server there is additional latency -- when I add a product or login to my application it takes a couple of seconds before it carries out the action.

Any tips or other method to sync data from other branches to just 1 database?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about programming problems and belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or maybe http://serverfault.com/.

Comment: sorry for the off topic

Answer (score 1):

> **Location, Resources and Load** concerning the DNS server; this are the
>   factors that increases or decrease the performance of your DNS server.
>   Try to optimize this factor.
>
> If you want **full speed use your IP** itself to connect to the DB server,
>   this will eliminate the DNS resolution time.
>
> You can also **use cloudflare or similar DNS service**; they are both
>   fast and secure (I think it is free also).

Comment: was the answer useful?